# How to read locked file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to download a PDF file generated with SelectPdf, but whe I try to read the newly created file I get an error because the file is locked and cannot be opened.

This is my code:

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();
SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl("http://myurl.com");
doc.Save("mydocument.pdf");
doc.Close();
string fileName = "mydocument.pdf", myStringWebResource = null;
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myStringWebResource = fileName;
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);
```

Is there a way to download the locked file?

Comment: Use more real web paths, the problem could be there but your attempts to "hide your real site" could be also hiding your problem, use `http://example.com` for the url base, [that is what it is there for](http://www.example.com/).Right now your last line is performing the call `myWebClient.DownloadFile("mydocument.pdf","mydocument.pdf");` which is most defiantly not correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd like to assign my files correct paths, but I really don't know how Windows Servers work, or what will be the definitive URL for the project I'm working in.

Comment: If the file is locked, then you cannot read it. You need to find out why the file is locked. Why are you using WebClient? Where are you trying to put the file?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the "locked file" error because what you are really calling is `myWebClient.DownloadFile("mydocument.pdf","mydocument.pdf");`

So you a trying to download a local file into the same local file, hence the error.

Probably you do not want to do that. What exactly are you trying to achieve?